# Google Closure localization using goog.getMsg() method

Tags: cordova, localization, google-closure-library

Hi has anyone tried localizing their applications using google closure goog.getMsg() method. The issue is i am not able to get how to load the external file which contains translated strings and use them in the js file where we want to change the strings based on the locale change. I have referred the Closure: the definitive guide book but it has just provided the syntax, but fails to explain the file handling.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I used globalization.js instead its very handy and easy.

Comment: Here is a Java way: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/CbaSCJFin1g